# Creating a unique sequential (non PK) DB Value

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a table which contains products numbers. Each artikel belongs to some producent. When user creates his product the new number is genearted. Depends on producent articel starts with specific number and then its followed by new number increased by 1 in second section of entire number. Example is shown below:

```
Producent: X (12 as start number)
12.1001.1
12.1002.1
12.1003.1

Producent: Y (4 as start number)
4.1001.1
4.1002.1
4.1003.1
4.1004.1
4.1005.1
4.1006.1
```

I have wizard on windows form with next/back buttons user picks producent and the number is generated - by this i mean there is sql query which is looking for the highest number of already available for specific producent for instance for Producent Y next will be `4.1006.1` so new number will be `4.1007.1`. At the moment when application is getting next number this number is not inserted into table but later after couple diffrent things user has to finalize. At the moment this number is saved into variable to be inserted after all other things at the end of process.

The problem is when other user is creating his article for same producent his wizard will give him same number as for previous user as the mentioned number is still not there in the table so he get same number as previous user.

How you would workaround this issue? What i have on mind is to have additional table in db so when new number is generated it would go to this table and every other user besides generated his number would check also the new table whether number is there and increment it again. Of course every user after work is finish the application would clear that table from this entry. The one issue i have on mind here is what if for instance for whatever reason any application would be closed by error or whatever then this table will not clear the entry.

How you would do on my side?

Comment: Please share some code and where you have problem in it.

Comment: I do apologise but your question does rant on quite a bit; please refine it so we can understand what you're asking. I'm flagging to close as unclear for this reason. **Your edit removes critical information from the question.**

Comment: I tried to make it shorter as it was before. This is not about the code but the apprach which could be done to avoid that situation. Generally new number is not inserted at the momoment but other user will generate the same as the number is not in table so other users will get same numbers.

Comment: @JimmyJimm If you're asking for opinions (i.e `what should I do?`), your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. We need code to work with, theory is dealt with over at Programmers.SE but your question may be off-topic there, too.

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: Why not generate the number the the entity is saved instead? (It cant show up on the screen until after it is saved though)

Comment: that's hard to explain because this number (still not in db) is used to lof of staff in wizard in further process. I can't do that. The only one way i see is to store somwhere this number so other users would not take the same.

Comment: Can this number be randomly generated?

Comment: Which database are you using?  The code could produce the first part, then the rest could be finished by a Trigger when it is saved.  A little like a PK

Comment: @Plutonix That's what I was thinking, but it sounds like to me the OP wants to avoid too many database calls.

Comment: @JimmyJimm What about the situation where User A gets a new number `4.1007.1`, then User B gets a new number `4.1008.1`, then User A cancels the process. Is the next number to be generated `4.1007.1` or `4.1009.1`?

Comment: I just tested a trigger and it works marvelously...but we dont even know the DB.

Comment: @Verdolino good point - this situation could also be there but should not be, i just don;t know how to solve that. P.S Plutonix do you propose trigger or?

Comment: The problem with such broad questions is that we know *nothing*.  There is a very good chance that any attempt to help will result in these things trickling out *well, I cant do xyz because the foo needs to comply with ISO976.(b) and blah blah blah* It ends up being a waste of everyone's time

Comment: @Plutonix you right i made diffrent topic which should be moved to more like sql server question please visit if you like and want to help, i close this one. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582240/trigger-to-supervise-and-modify-values-if-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great deal we dont know: which database?, how is the data being stored and read from the DB? How is thing being stored (as 1 string or as 3 ints)?

As a result, this is a *conceptual* solution.  If these need to be unique and sequential, then you can't really determine the value unless and until it is saved to the DB.  If sequence gaps are allowed, you have it a little easier - you could burn values when a record isn't saved.  Hitting a counter table is wasteful if your DB supports Triggers.  Using a simple table, in MySQL:

`{ID int(11), Name (varchar), Descr (varchar), Major (int), Minor (int), Revision (int)}`

If you are storing it as one string value, you may want to rethink that - individually they have meaning and are also being manipulated that way, so they are distinct data elements.  You can easily CONCAT them in SQL or convert them to a `System.Version` type in code.  Add a before insert trigger:

```
BEGIN
    SET @maxR = 0;
    SET @maxR = (SELECT Max(Minor) FROM jamversion WHERE Major = NEW.Major);
    If (ISNUll(@maxR)) THEN 
        SET @maxR = 1000;
    END IF;
    SET NEW.Minor = @maxR + 1;
END
```

You may need to add a LOCK, but we dont even know what the DB is.

Your code would not pass the `Minor` value, the db supplies it.  Adding a row using SQL and `ExecuteNonQuery` your have to go get the record to see the value used.  Using a `DataTable` and a `DataAdapter` you could refresh.  A quick test:

[image]

I added 100 rows each with a random `Major` value between 1 and 5.  When sorted by Major:

[image] the Minor values are unique
[image] Minor increment sequentially
[image] the `Id`s are also in ascending order by Minor, indicating that the order inserted matches

---

In other situations, before inserting a record, you could use a stored procedure to insert a new row with creating the `"X.YYYY.Z"` string value from some values passed. Maybe DBNull or -1 is the instruction to create that segment similar to the above.  Then return that value for you to do the insert.

Comment: thx for your post - if you would like to know exactly how situation looks please visit this long topic post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582240/trigger-to-supervise-and-modify-values-if-required

Comment: Awesome use of embedded pictures